# Can a custom directive replace its element with a template that contains ng-show?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, ng-show

I want to build a simple `hello` directive that is to be used like so:

```
<hello foo="bar"></hello>
```

If the `foo` attribute equals "bar", I want to replace the element with `<div ng-show="true"></div>"`; otherwise, replace it with `<div ng-show="false"></div>"`. However, I only one want to replace the `hello` element, not any of the children nested inside it!

So for example:

```
<hello foo="bar">
  <h1>Hi everyone!</h1>
</hello>
```

Would be replaced by this:

```
<div ng-show="true">
  <h1>Hi everyone!</h1>
</div>
```

Is this even possible to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve that by using transclusion:

**Javascript**

```
app.directive('hello', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    transclude: true,
    replace: true,
    scope: { foo: '@' },
    template: '<div ng-show="foo == \'bar\'" ng-transclude></div>',
  };
});
```

**HTML**

```
<hello foo="bar">
  <h1>Hi everyone!</h1>
</hello>

<hello foo="baz">
  <h1>Hi everybody!</h1>
</hello>
```

Working Plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/VakoY9LZtMEzexvLejva?p=preview).

Comment: @XåpplI'-I0llwlg'I- I realize this is what you _wanted_ to do, but I still fail to see why you think this is better.  It hides information about the resulting behavior without having intimate knowledge that this magic value changes something.  If you could show a more complete example of what you are trying to accomplish, it would really help the question.

Comment: @XåpplI'-I0llwlg'I- Please notice that this solution won't render the exact markup you are expecting. If you really want the directive to render `<div ng-show="true">`, then @BuuNguyen solution seems to be the correct one.

Comment: I never said it was better. I wanted to know whether it was possible.

Answer (score 1):

Dynamically injecting a directive while compiling/linking another directive is a hairy business. You can't simply set the attribute because it won't be collected by Angular. Manual compilation wouldn't work either because it will cause infinite loop. That being said, if you have already decided that this is what you want :), here you go:

```
app.directive('hello', function($injector) {
  return {
    transclude: true,
    replace: true,
    restrict: "E",
    template: "<div ng-transclude></div>",
    compile: function(tele, tattrs) {
      var ngShow = $injector.get("ngShowDirective")[0];
      return function(scope, ele, attrs) {
        attrs.$set("ngShow", (attrs.foo === "bar").toString());
        ngShow.link(scope, ele, attrs);
      }
    }
  }
});
```

The idea is to manually link the the `ngShow` directive instead of relying on AngularJS to do that. Normally, only AngularJS invokes `compile` and `link`; plus, this code relies on the knowledge that `ngShow` has a `link` function. In general, it should be considered a hack and used with care.

[Demo link](http://plnkr.co/edit/R5clhN75eyIA6W0C7AR5?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to apply the `ng-show` attribute to the `hello` element and check a property of the model to see if it should be hidden.

```
<hello ng-show="foo == 'bar'">
    <h1>Hi everyone!</h1>
</hello>
```

And on a scope that is accessible by this view you'd have a foo property.

```
$scope.foo = 'bar';
```

Comment: How would I apply it? And what model property am I checking? Please be more specific.

Comment: There is not enough information about your model for me to give an exact answer, but if you're specifying the foo attribute to be bar, you could either set ng-show directly in place of that, or you can reference a scope variable in ng-show, which I have updated the answer to give an example for.